# AWS Certificate Manager and Route 53 approve SSL certificates

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53, aws-acm

I run a SaaS with multiple subdomains and with the option for customers to use their own domains too.

This means, that we host eg:

```
customer1.ourdomain.com
customer2.ourdomain.com
www.customer3.com
www.customer4.com
```

When creating a certificate through ACM, I have to confirm the new certificate for all domains, that's fair, as I can live with that.
But our customers can't live with confirming their domain everytime we add a new certificate (since we still can't update/add domains to an existing cert.).

My question is, can I, somehow intercept the mails that are being send out, when the domains has to be confirmed?
Of cause I can't always get their mails, but just for eg. hostmaster@customer3.com

The domains can be moved to Route 53 if needed, the customers usually have had them in a long time, hosted somewhere else. We usually just make a CNAME to our ELB.

How do other people deal with this?

Best regards, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Currently**, you have two options here:
Firstly, AWS allows you to configure the base domain name to which you want the validation email to be sent. For instance, you are requesting SSL for subdomains like `*.customer1.ourdomain.com` or `*.customer2.ourdomain.com` you can specify `ourdomain.com` as the validation domain.

> Can I configure the email addresses to which the certificate approval
>   request is sent? No, but you can configure the base domain name to
>   which you want the validation email to be sent. The base domain name
>   must be a superdomain of the domain name in the certificate request.
>   For example, if you want to request a certificate for
>   server.domain.example.com but want to direct the approval email to
>   admin@domain.example.com, you can do so using the AWS CLI or API. See
>   ACM CLI Reference and ACM API Reference for further details.

To enhance this process even further you can try [acmagent](https://github.com/b-b3rn4rd/acmagent) pip library to automate you SSL confirmation

```
pip install acmagent
```

Requesting SSL

```
$ acmagent request-certificate --domain-name *.dev.example.com --validation-domain example.com
12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012
```

Approving SSL

```
$ acmagent confirm-certificate --certificate-id 12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012
```

More examples can be found [here](https://github.com/b-b3rn4rd/acmagent/blob/master/README.rst).

The second option is to create a MX record in the hosted zone pointing to the SES service and use Lambda function to parse the confirmation email body. I found an existing project that looks like is doing this already: [aws-acm-certificate-request-approver](https://github.com/cjdev/aws-acm-certificate-request-approver)

Hopefully, that helps.